# How would I test if a string contains a certain word (using Ruby)?

Tags: ruby, match

I want to test to see if a string called `note.attachment_content_type` contains the word `"image"`. How would I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `String#include?`

`note.attachment_content_type.include?("image")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Regexp`:

```
if note.attachment_content_type =~ /image/
   puts "Found"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`String#[]`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D)

```
note.attachment_content_type[/image/]
```

Comment: Hi Arup. I'm curious as to your reasoning. Why use `Sring#[]` over `String#include?` or a regex match?

Comment: @Silasj No..`Sring#[]` not over `String#include?`.. Just another way.. Did you ever use it? I mean `String#[]` ? :)

Comment: I've rarely used `String#[]`. Usually I use `#slice`. I'd have never thought of this way... Guess that's the beauty of ruby.